# self-join (inner join) generates cartesian product

Tags: sql, inner-join, sql-server-2016, cross-join

Data

```
origin  OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID
ATL     19790
ATL     19790
ATL     19790
ATL     19790
ATL     19790
ATL     19790
ATL     19790
ATL     19790
ATL     19790
ATL     19790

BWI     19790
BWI     19790
BWI     19790
BWI     19790
BWI     19790
BWI     19790
BWI     19790
```

In the data I have I am trying to find find a correct way to match in the following format

```
Origin[Airlines]Origin
```

I am trying to create a relationship between two cities, say first Origin is Origin city and the second origin is Destination city.

```
select origin, a.OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID, count(*) cnt 
from a_Dec a 
where a.OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID= '19790 'and a.origin ='ATL' 
group by origin, a.OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID
```

I get

```
origin  OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID   cnt
ATL    19790                    19201
```

which is correct, that is there were 19201 flights originated in ATL.

Now I want to treat second Origin as Destination and I used following query

```
select a.OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID, a.origin, b.origin,  count(*) cnt  
from  [dbo].[a_Dec] a  
left join  [dbo].[a_Dec] b 
  on (a.OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID = b.OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID)
where a.OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID is not null  
  and a.origin is not null 
group by a.OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID, a.origin, b.origin
having count(*)> 1
order by cnt desc
```

An example of result

```
OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID   origin  origin  cnt
19790                    ATL    ATL 368678401
19805                    DFW    DFW 141158161
19790                    MSP    ATL 96389020
19790                    ATL    BWI 96389020
```

`368678401` is the result of above `19201*19201`, which is essentially cartesian product.

this is a wrong query, I know but how would I be able to form a relationship for this? Actually,

`19790 ATL ATL 368678401` or `19805    DFW DFW 141158161` line even should not exist in result. 
Please note that this is essentially creating an egde as called in graph database, but in situation when there is no graph databse available, how do we solve this mystery in plain sql?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Your two columns do not have the origin/destination information you are looking for, so the information is not in the table you described.

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.  A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly". Please in code questions give a [mre]. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: The root cause of the problem is that you are performing a self join between result sets that do not have keys. Each side of the equation, includes multiple rows with the same values (19201 to be exact) that are joined againts the other multiple rows. The solution? Add a key to the rows: maybe the table already has it, but you are not showing it.

Comment: Impaler, correct, its because of the self-join and the table does have other attributes but keys are not defined.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: philipxy, I think I have provided enough example above, if you read through. I know its long but trying to wrap head around this issue if possible to get it done. Please note that, this can be done in graph database, I am just not very efficient with SQL

Comment: Hi @lpt, I think you have written a lot here and a nice job, vote up. But please can you do this: First time you write "I get" and then result, can you give us the result that you get from the data you have given us(not from the data you have in your database with thousands of records...). Also do the same thing with "An example of result". And then at the end please give us the expected result(also using only data you have given us)... This way we can code and test and give you some code that might work for you data... Cheers!